# Amibroker AFL: How to plot Custom Anchored VWAP (AVWAP) passing any specific date to it

Tags: stock, algorithmic-trading, trading, amibroker

Below is the code for Anchored VWAP which will select Date based on my mouse click, my query is how to plot Anchored VWAP passing date as a parameter, so it will be constant across all symbols.

Eg: I want to pass "2021-03-26" as Date parameter so it will plot AVWAP starting from "2021-03-26" date.

```
_SECTION_BEGIN("CustomAVWAP");
dn = DateTime();
sd = SelectedValue( dn );
start = dn == sd;

mp = C;
PV = mp * V;
CV = Cum( V );
VSS = CV - ValueWhen( start, CV );
denom = IIf( VSS == 0, 1, VSS );
num = Cum( PV ) - ValueWhen( start, Cum( PV ) );
M = IIf( BarsSince( start ), num/denom, mp );

Plot( C, Date() + " Close", colorBrightGreen, styleBar );
Plot( M, "PSVWAP", colorBrightGreen, styleThick );

_SECTION_END();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `sd = SelectedValue( dn );`
into
`sd = DateTimeConvert( 2, 1210326 );`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).